# magento 2 session

Tags: session, magento2.2

In my installation of the **Magento 2.2**. I have a strange misbehavior related to sessions. Specifically: I can't get any data from session after the browser page has been refreshed.

As result I have an "**empty**" session for admin customer and I can't authorize to magento admin panel(redirect loop).

The files of the session are created(I can see them).
I have been trying to use different windows server(**open server**) and vagrant(**Homestead**) and it's always the same.

The Redis has the same issue: Magento doesn't return value from the session storage.

Always prints "**SET**". `$value` is **NULL**:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $session */
$session = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session');
$value = $session->getMyValue();
if (is_null($value)) {
     echo 'SET';
     $session->setMyValue('test');
} else {
     echo $session->getMyValue();
}
```

Comment: clear browser cookies and try again

Comment: This was the first thing which I did and also, I have tried to use different browser

Answer (score 0):

You can get customer session regardless of enabling full page caching or not.

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
<?php $context = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context'); ?>
<?php $isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH); ?>
    <?php if($isLoggedIn) : ?>
        // logged-in 
    <?php else: ?>  
        // not-logged in 
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end, the issue has been resolved after I have installed the ubuntu on my laptop. So I can assume that it was something with my env configs.